# How to move view down by animation?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, core-animation

In my app, I implement webview, and under that webview I have a one view and I want to move that view by animation like in Safari.

Here is my code:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y > 0 {
        // scrolls down
        print("UP")
        viewbottom.hidden = false
        viewHieght.constant = 45
    } else {
        print("DOWN")
        viewbottom.hidden = true
        viewHieght.constant = 0
    }
}
```

In this code I am hiding the view while scroll down but I want to move it down slowly like Safari. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `layoutIfNeeded()` property with `animateWithDuration`

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        viewHieght.constant = 45
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHeight.constant = max(0, min(45, scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y))
```

This should make the view move with the gesture but min be 0 and max be 45